# Visual Studio macro writes extra " mark

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xslt, macros

I thought i'd use a macro to speed up writing `<xsl:choose>` blocks.

```
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "<xsl:choose>"
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine()
```

gives me (thanks to auto complete)

```
<xsl:choose>

</xsl:choose>
```

however

```
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "<xsl:choose>"
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine()
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "<xsl:when test=""true()"">"
```

gives

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="true()"></xsl:when>"
</xsl:choose>
```

in the editor.

Where is that extra " coming from??

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hehe, it's the autocomplete. When the macro types the = symbol the ide adds the quote marks and moves the cursor, then the macro continues typing where i'm not expecting it to be.

D'oh.

```
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "<xsl:choose>"
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine()
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "<xsl:when test=true()"
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = ">"
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.NewLine()
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you escape the "" with \"

```
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "<xsl:when test=\"true()\"/>"
```